# Django MultipleObjectsReturned at /author/Ed Sheeran get() returned more than one Songs -- it returned 2

Tags: django

I was coding a song viewing website with Django then suddenly came across this error

`MultipleObjectsReturned at /author/Ed Sheeran get() returned more than one Songs -- it returned 2!`

I was trying to set up my website such that when users click on the name of the author of any song, they will be redirected to another page where there are songs of that author only. But unfortunately, my code is running into this error.

My models.py:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    lyrics = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    track_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('/', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My views.py:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'songs': Songs.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

class AuthorSongListView(ListView):
    model = Songs
    template_name = 'author_songs.html'
    context_object_name = 'songs'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        author = get_object_or_404(Songs, author=self.kwargs.get('author'))
        return Songs.objects.filter(author=author)
```

My html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1 class="mb-3">Songs by {{ view.kwargs.author }}</h1>
{% for song in songs %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'author-songs' song.author %}">{{ song.author }}</a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'song-detail' song.id %}">{{ song.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ song.lyrics }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Ed Sheeran has 2 songs in the table you have to use a filter there instead of get_object_or_404 and if there are no songs then raise an exception and catch it blow.

Comment: Can you please show me where to make changes, it would have been really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is popping up because `Model.objects.get(**args)` should always return 1 result. If it finds more than 1 result, it throws this error.

In this code:

```py
class AuthorSongListView(ListView):
    model = Songs
    template_name = 'author_songs.html'
    context_object_name = 'songs'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        author = get_object_or_404(Songs, author=self.kwargs.get('author'))
        return Songs.objects.filter(author=author)
```

This is the line that is throwing error

```py
author = get_object_or_404(Songs, author=self.kwargs.get('author'))

# this is trying to fetch Songs for the given author like this
Songs.objects.get(author=self.kwargs.get('author'))
# Since there are multiple songs for the author, this is throwing error.
```

What you need to do is update the method `get_queryset` like this:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
   return Songs.objects.filter(author=self.kwargs.get('author'))
```